# difference between normal function declaration and inside return block function declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between normal function declaration and inside return block function declaration in Javascript.

Below code normal function name : updatename, inside function name : changeName

```
function person(firstName,lastName,age,eyeColor) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.eyeColor = eyeColor;

    this.updatename = function (name) {
        this.lastName = name;
    }

    return {

        'changeName' :  function (name) {
            this.lastName = name;
        }
    }; 

}
var myMother = new person("Sally","Rally",48,"green");

console.dir(myMother);

console.log(typeof(myMother.changeName));

console.log(typeof(myMother.updatename));

myMother.changeName("Doe");
```

Comment: That's not a return block. It's an object literal.

Comment: if comment out normal function and execute above code typeof(myMother.changeName) returning function.

Comment: They are both functions. There is no difference from language perspective. They come from different scopes, though but that's about it.

Comment: When you call a function with `new` the function should not return anything. The `new` keyword will return the function's `this`. I repeat: the `new` keyword returns an object, not the constructor.

Comment: yep, js is not allowing to declare both type of function if i declare return block code is overriding  normal block type will be undefined

Comment: thanks slebetman, if enable return block new keyword is returning Object inside only function changeName is available other declared object properties not available. if is disable return block new keyword is returning person object with all properties and updatename  function aswell

Comment: If you return an object from a function, then invoke that as a constuctor with `new`, the `this` of the function is THROWN AWAY AND IGNORED AND LOST FOREVER. In other words, the value of `this.firstName` is never again accessible in this world. What are you trying to accomplish by returning that object literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return an object from a function, then invoke that as a constructor with `new`, the original `this` of the function is THROWN AWAY AND IGNORED AND LOST FOREVER. In other words, the value of `this.firstName` is never again accessible in this world. What are you trying to accomplish by returning that object literal?

> What is the difference between normal function declaration and inside return block function declaration in JavaScript?

The difference (assuming you mean **method** declaration) is that the normal declaration does what you would normally imagine it would do. The "inside return block function declaration" overrides and cancels the original value of `this`, and instead returns JUST THAT OBJECT with a single method, which is probably not what you want.